# Query to show one column multiplied

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

I have the following 3 tables;

**Table_Names**:

```
user_id   Name  
------------------
  1       Mark
  2       Tom
  3       Ana
```

**Table_Language**:

```
language_id    Language
-----------------------
    1          English
    2          German
```

**Table_Name_Lang**

```
id   user_id   language_id
---------------------------
 1     1          1
 2     1          2
 3     2          1
 4     3          2
```

How can I create a query to show the expected results like those below?

```
Name    Expr_1_Eng   Expr_1_Ger
---------------------------------
Mark    English      German
Tom     English
Ana                  German
```

Thanks Tok

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
select n.name,
       max(case when l.language = 'English' then l.language end) as has_English,
       max(case when l.language = 'German' then l.language end) as has_German
from names n join
     name_lang nl
     on nl.user_id = n.user_id join
     lang l
     on nl.language_id = l.language_id
group by n.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `JOIN` with condition aggregate function

```
SELECT Name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN tnl.language_id = 1 then tl.Language end),
    MAX(CASE WHEN tnl.language_id = 2 then tl.Language end)
FROM 
Table_Name_Lang tnl 
JOIN Table_Names tn on tnl.language_id = tn.language_id
JOIN Table_Language tl on tl.user_id = tnl.user_id
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: THx Please help , what does it mean in sintax tnl.  amd tl. ?

Comment: It's an alias name for tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use pivot:

```
   select n.name,[0] as language_one,[1] as language_two,[2],[3] from 
    (select n.name,tl.language
    tablename n
    left join Table_Name_Lang tnl on n.userid=tnl.userid
    left join table_language tl on tl.id=tnl.id
    group by n.name,tl.language
    )T
    pivot
    (
    language
    for name in [0],[1],[2],[3]
    )AS PivotTable;
```